Как зайти на нужную мне API страницу, используя выданный мне токен для авторизации
Мне нужно перейти по странице https://lms.yandex.ru/api/profile чтобы взять оттуда данные пользователя моей программы, и в документации Yandex написано о том, что для того чтобы получить эту информацию мне потребуется токен. Токен я благополучно получил, а вот как попасть на страницу так и не понял.
Вот мой незамысловатый код:
import fake_useragent

uk = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
user_agent = uk.random

token = 'my token'
url = 'https://lms.yandex.ru/api/profile'

headers = {'Authorization': token, 'User-Agent': user_agent}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)

Выдаёт ошибку доступа (401)

Не смог найти документацию по api, можно ссылку? Пока просто предположу возможно вместо Authorization должен быть X-Auth-Key, по крайней мере он используется для api-developer.tech.yandex.net
